# zsh’s tab completion overwrites what's next

Tags: zsh, tab-completion, completion

If I write some command line and I forget to put something in the middle, I normally go back and start typing there

```sh
% command --option -s █  --something-else
                      ^ cursor
```

Then I might want to use the autocomplete feature, so I press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. In my configuration (which I'll post below) two things can happen:

1. If there is only one option, the expected behavior happens

```
(type "lon")
% command --option -s lon█  --something-else
(press TAB)
% command --option -s long_folder/█  --something-else
```

2. If there are multiple options the first <kbd>TAB</kbd> press will show a list of alternatives and any arrow key will write the first alternative in the command line. Unfortunately, if I do this, the following text is not shifted but rather overwritten

```
% command --option -s lon█  --something-else
(press TAB)
interactive: lon[]
long_folder/  loong_folder/  whatever/
(press arrow down)
% command --option -s long_folder/█hing-else
```

As you can see pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> overwrites part of what was next. How to avoid this?

---

Relevant part of my `.zshrc`

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

setopt noautomenu
setopt globcomplete
bindkey '^i' complete-word
setopt nolisttypes

zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes select interactive
```

The last line is responsible for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that that’s a bug in `zsh`. I’ve submitted a [bug report on the Z Shell mailing list](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01466.html) about it.

Comment: Very appreciated, let's hope it gets fixed soon. Cheers.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to address this?

Comment: I have not received any replies to my bug report: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01466.html

Comment: Feel free to follow up on it on the mailing list. In the meantime, do you think you could Accept my answer? 

Comment: I don't know the mailing list rules. Is it acceptable to send an email there just to bump an old post?

Comment: Yes, that’s perfectly fine. It’s preferred if you reply directly to the email in question, but it’s also fine if you refer to it by ID, which is in this case is `workers/49242`.